# Paper Folding Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

Hi friends is it possible to create PAPER FOLD animations in android.Like,i iPhone i have knowledge about property animations like that.But,i don't know whether it is possible in Android or not.

Comment: Curl effect or folding effect (like http://pinterest.com/pin/489485053219968173/)?

Comment: folding efeect i wanted

Comment: I developed a library some time ago in order to render a proper folding animation, and I mean to release that on github anytime soon. I'll post here the link when ready, if you are interested to have a look :)

Answer (score 3):

You got this library on Google code : https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/
And this one on GitHub : https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/FoldingLayout.zip try this for fold animation supports Api level 11+

Answer (score 0):

PageCurl using renderscript

https://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/wiki/PageCurl

Renderscript

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

Renderscript tutorial

http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/08/24/renderscript-101-part-1-renderscript-basics-tutorial/